# Remove Items from array based on Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have MAinArray

```
MainArray=[{
{First Name: "First Name"},
{Last Name: "Contact"},
{Last Name: "Contact"}
]
```

I want to remove key ,value pair from this array such as

```
if (key == 'First Name')
{
delete MainArray[key] /// this doesnt work
}
```

the final result must be

```
ResultArray=[{
    {Last Name: "Contact"},
    {Last Name: "Contact"}
    ]
```

Comment: For Arrays you want to use [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), not delete

Comment: This does not work because `MainArray` is an indexed array and not an object. Thus `delete MainArray[key]` fails due to `MainArray[key]` not being defined. Had you used `delete MainArray[0]` the entry would have gotten deleted (note: deleted, not removed from the array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `filter` and inside that takes `Object.keys` of that current Object and check if it includes the given filter:

```js
var MainArray=[ {'First Name': "First Name"}, {'Last Name': "Contact"}, {'Last Name': "Contact"} ];

var result = MainArray.filter(item=>!Object.keys(item).includes('First Name'));

var result2 = MainArray.filter(item=>!item['First Name']);

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Works, yet this creates a new unnecessary object, which was, technically seen, not the question.

Answer (score 0):

The **filter()** method can also be used to remove items based on given conditions, see below example:

```js
let data=[
{"First Name": "First Name"},
{"First Name": "First Name"},
{"Last Name": "Contact"},
{"Last Name": "Contact"}
]

const keyToRemove = "First Name"; //Key to remove

data = data.filter(x => !x[keyToRemove]);

console.log(data);
```